# What does constructive mathematics say about limits?

Tags: constructive-mathematics

Suppose I want to construct a mathematical proof using constructive mathematics. Let's say I've reached a proof statement where I've shown that, say, x = 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ..., whereupon I would like to introduce the proposition, x = 1. Clearly, this would be allowed in conventional mathematics, but are limits considered valid in constructive mathematics? That is, is there a constructive proof that this infinite sequence converges, given that it is an infinite series? (Is an infinite series constructible?) Please take into account that I'm just a novice when it comes to constructive mathematics.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\dots=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} = \lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{2^n}$.  This expression on the far right should still be well understood and although $\infty$ appears in the notation, no infinite quantities are involved in the meaning.

Comment: You should mention which system of "constructive mathematics" you are using.  See, for example, E. Bishop, *Foundations of Constructive Analysis*.

Comment: You may be interested in the book "Reverse Mathematics Proofs from the Inside out" by John Stillwell. Here is a link to one book seller https://www.biggerbooks.com/reverse-mathematics-stillwell-john/bk/9780691177175&referrer=adcenterp

Comment: From what little I know about these things, I would think that your example would not be provable in a framework of finitism or ultrafinitism, which is different from constructivism.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, limits are valid in constructive mathematics.

The statement $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = x$ is, as usual, defined to mean $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \forall n \in \mathbb{N} (n \geq N \implies |a_n - x| < \epsilon)$.

It can be shown constructively that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} = 0$. For consider some $\epsilon > 0$. Then take $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{\epsilon} < N$. Now consider some $m > N$. Then $0 < \frac{1}{\epsilon} < N < m < 2^m$, so therefore $0 < \frac{1}{2^m} < \epsilon$. Thus, $|\frac{1}{2^m} - 0| < \epsilon$.

Notice that only constructive logic was required to do this proof. Similarly, only constructive logic is required to show that $1/2 + 1/4 + ... + \frac{1}{2^n} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^n}$. This can be done easily by induction.

So we see that $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} 1 - \frac{1}{2^n} = 1 - \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} = 1 - 0 = 1$.

Note that in the absence of a very weak form of countable choice known as $AC_{0, 0}$, a second, stronger definition of limit is sometimes required. This definition is: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = x$ if and only if there exists a function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n > 0$, for all $m > f(n)$, $|a_m - x| < \frac{1}{n}$. This stronger definition implies the weaker definition, but not necessarily vice versa.

Answer (score 9):

The situation where limits get problematic in a constructive treatment is if the speed of convergence is not known. For very concrete examples such as yours, the speed of convergence is obviously known, and everything is fine.

Lets construct an example of a sequence which is converging classically but not constructively (for most flavours of "constructive").

Let $a_t := \sum_{\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid \text{the $n$-th TM halts in at most $t$ steps}\}} 2^{-n}$. This is a computable sequence of reals. This sequence clearly is monotonely increasing and bounded above by $2$. Classically, this would mean that it converges. However, if we knew its (classical) limit  $a_\infty := \sum_{\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid \text{the $n$-th TM halts}\}} 2^{-n}$, we could solve the Halting problem. Hence, $a_\infty$ is not a computable real -- hence $(a_t)_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ doesn't converge in a constructive sense.

In case you aren't familiar with Turing machines yet: Unfortunately, there isn't a good way around them to get decent counterexample to stuff being constructive.

Comment: I am familiar with Turing machines. Thank you for your clear analysis.

Comment: @StephenMorgan If you found my answer helpful, please upvote it (grey arrow pointed up on the left), and do the same for the other good answers. If there is an answer fitting your needs best, you can accept it by selecting the checkmark.

Comment: Precisely: constructive sense is not able to decide if it converges or not. It does not mean it does not converge because then we would have some information about Turing machines. We have none.

Comment: @AlexPeter Its meant to be read "doesn't (converge in a constructive sense)" not "(doesn't converge) in a constructive sense". For the latter statement it matters a lot what framework we use. Eg BISH will sit on the fence regarding convergence, whereas Russian constructivism can prove that the sequence doesnt converge.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between classical and constructive definition is that you are not taking for granted, using the fact that it is *as close as* you want to $1$, that

$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{32}...=1$$

Constructively, you are saying that you want to know if this has any sense:

$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{32}...+\frac{1}{2^n}=1$$

because that is the best you can do. Now, purely constructively, you say, ok I want this to be close to $1$ by $\epsilon$. And now you find that if you take

$$n=\ln_2(\frac1{\epsilon})$$

you are right there since

$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{32}...+\frac{1}{2^n}=1-\frac{1}{2^n}=1-\epsilon$$

Since, by this construction, you can get as close as you specifically(!) wish, you consider these expressions equal. Notice that in constructive math it is not exactly about the expression itself, it is about the process. Both of these together are $1$

$$f(n)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{32}...+\frac{1}{2^n}, g(n)=n$$

This is to say: since I can select always a specific natural number by which I am getting close to $1$ by any predefined distance, I consider this equal to $1$ (because there is no difference between them which you could fix in advance and call it *the difference* between $1$ and the expression. If you do, I can use the above expression and quickly calculate which $n$ to take and disprove that difference of yours).

In constructive math, you never get into some classical realm of meta, you are firmly routed into procedural steps of getting from one point to another.

Answer (score -2):

I am especially confused by references in the provided answers to Turing machines, as that is what prompted my question in the first place. As I understand it, the sum 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + … cannot be constructed on a Turing machine in a finite number of steps. Suppose we agree that a mark at a certain tape location stands for 1/2, and a mark one place to its right stands for 1/4, and the mark to its right 1/8, ad infinitum. It would take the entire right-hand side of the Turing machine tape to represent the infinite-precision real number corresponding to the sequence, and an infinite sequence of steps merely to construct the sequence, to say nothing of the program necessary to conclude that the sum was equal to 1. Given that the sum is therefore not constructible on a Turing machine, I assumed (possibly incorrectly) that it was not allowable in constructive mathematics.

Comment: There is a difference between "Turing Machines" and "constructive Math". Constructive math is achieved by using a different logical system for doing mathematical proofs; one that does not use the law of excluded middle (but there are even different flavors of constructivism as mentioned by Arno). Turing machines are a model of how computation works, and this model can be defined/described in ordinary classical math or constructive math. Talking about Turing machines does not automatically mean you are working in constructive mathematics.

Comment: In this case it means that to constructively show that your mentioned sum converges to $1$, there is no reason to bring Turing machines into the discussion. We only need to make sure that the proof only uses constructive logic.

Comment: According to the Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy, “Constructive mathematics is often mis-characterized as classical mathematics… without the Law of Excluded Middle” (see https://iep.utm.edu/con-math). While I agree that CM excludes the LEM, I believe that follows from the definition of CM, that every term of every proposition introduced be construtible (ibid). Classical mathematics without LEM allows one to reach conclusions that are not provable according to the constructive definition. The sum in question does not seem to be constructible on a Turing machine, so not introducible.

Comment: Yes, the "logic without LEM" is a simplified, very incomplete description, but a good way to give the jist of it. Your description does indeed strongly point to there being no Turing machine computing the result of the series. The point is however that CM can prove that the series converges and Turing machines play no role in that proof.

Comment: Every constructive argument of the convergence of the series given thus far relies explicitly or implicitly on the assertion that an infinite series is constructible, which was really the basis of my original question. Without merely asserting explicitly or implicitly that infinite series are indeed constructible and therefore allowed by CM, does there exist a philosophical argument to suggest that they are constructible and if so, by what means (other than Turing machines)?

Comment: Ah, I think I wasn't really aware of the "that an infinite series is constructible" part of your question up to this point. I guess it is mentioned by "Is an infinite series constructible?", but only in parantheses. So maybe you want to stress this more in your question, if you also want an answer from other users to this part. Whether infinite sequences can be defined at all then really depends on what kind of theory you start of with. But something like Peanon Arithmetic in a constructive logic is already capable of it.

Comment: Hmm. I believe I understand what you’ve said, although I’m still left confused. I understood “constructible” to mean in CM what it means in (say) plane geometry, that an object is constructible if and only if it may be created by the application of a straightedge, compass, and pencil within a finite number of steps. While I can represent a series that diminishes by half at each step using those instruments alone, I cannot represent an infinite such series in a finite number of steps. Thus, I concluded, such a series is not constructible. Similarly, arithmetic given the Peano axioms.

Comment: Of course, if I were allowed to construct objects geometrically using a straightedge, compass, and pencil but were not limited to doing so within a finite number of steps, I could trisect an angle or square the circle, two things known to be impossible (non-constructible) in a finite number of steps.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number

Comment: And here is what I meant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_real_number#Definability_in_arithmetic Note though that everything being talked about in your and my link is usually carried out in ordinary classical logic. It has (per se) nothing to do with constructive math in the sense of its usual meaning: "math in a constructive logic"

Comment: As I understand it, constructive mathematics allows arguments solely regarding terms that are constructible (hence the name), whereas classical mathematics has no such restriction. Only terms that are constructible provably exist. And a construction must be performable within a finite number of steps. I have yet to see how an infinite series is constructible. (I believe you’ve argued that it can be well-defined, but not that it is constructible.) Perhaps it would be best if you were to provide a construction in finite steps of the infinite series in question, to settle the issue.

Comment: At this point I can just refer you back to the answer by @MarkSaving. He describes the series in constructive mathematics and shows why we can still prove that it converges to $1$.

Comment: Kindly read https://www.jstor.org/stable/24965320